# Using a local WMTS server with ArcGIS Earth on iPad

Tags: wmts, ipad, arcgis-earth

I would like to use an open map tile server to server tiles to the ArcGIS Earth application running on my iPad. I would like to do this as the iPad is not always connected to the Internet, but will always be on the same network as the tile server.

Currently the tile server is running on a Synology NAS using the klokantech-tilserver-gl docker package. The ArcGIS Earth iOS version is 1.3.0

I tired to add a data source by adding the url for the tile server, an example is

- http://192.168.1.32:8080/styles/klokantech-basic/wmts.xml

Also tried

- http://192.168.1.32:8080/styles/klokantech-basic/wmts
- http://192.168.1.32:8080/styles/klokantech-basic/

Always get the same error messgae "Please input correct URL".

Answer (score 0):

The following from Esri:

> Unfortunately ArcGIS Earth for mobile doesn’t support for adding URL
> from a local server. We only support adding URLs from ArcGIS Online or
> ArcGIS Enterprise. (e.g. You can add a tile layer from ArcGIS Online
> using
> https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ab399b847323487dba26809bf11ea91a
> ).

So, not what I wanted to hear, but does indeed answer the question.